# why is my click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ()
{
   var $main = $('#main'),
    $1 = $('#1'),
    $2 = $('#2');

$2.hide(); // hide div#2 when the page is loaded

$main.click(function ()
{
    $1.toggle();
    $2.toggle();
});

 $senddvd.click(function ()
{
   alert('hello');
  // a=whichIsVisible();
   //alert(a);
});


function whichIsVisible()
{
    if (!$1.is(':hidden')) return $1;
    if (!$2.is(':hidden')) return $2;
}

});

</script>
```

The click on the main does seem to work not sure why its not working on senddvd

```
<div id="senddvd" align="center"><img   border="0"  src="images/senddvd.png"></div>
```

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't `$senddvd` be `$('#senddvd')`?

Comment: how do i check which value is returned by whichIsVisible()
the alert returns a [object Object]

Comment: Try `console.log(whichIsVisible())` in Firefox with Firebug installed. That should output the Element in the developer console.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare it :)

```
var $senddvd = $('#senddvd');
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing

```
var $senddvd = $('#senddvd');
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :

```
$('#senddvd').click(function ()
```

for this :

```
$senddvd.click(function ()
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/uXpVN/3/